# Nested while loop is not working with my GROUP BY queries

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop, group-by

I am a bit stuck with a `while` loop and need some assistance to find the wrong code.

My SQL table looks something like this:

```
make     model       model_body     variant   
M1       A           ooo            Va1    
M1       B           sss            Va2    
M1       B           sss            Va3    
M1       A           ooo            Va4
M1       A           ooo            Va5    
M1       B           jjj            Va6   
M1       A           www            Va7
```

I would like to output the table contents in HTML first by doing `GROUP BY` for `model_body` values and list only the unique ones with a loop and then with a second loop list all the available `variant` values for each uqniue `model_body`.

```
The output should look something like this:   However what I end up with is this:    

ooo    Va1                                    ooo    Va1
       Va4                                           Va4
       Va5                                           Va5
www    Va7                                    www              
sss    Va2                                    sss                
       Va3
jjj    Va6                                    jjj
```

The PHP code I wrote is this one, I tried several different possibilities but always end up with some kind of mismatch:

```
<?php while (!$rs_main_model->EOF)   { ?>                   
        <div>               
            <div>        
                <h2<?php echo $rs_main_model->fields['model']; ?></h2>
            </div>                                    
            <div>      
                      <?php while (!$rs_variant->EOF) { ?>                                  
                      <?php echo $rs_variant->fields['variant']; ?>
                      <?php $rs_variant->MoveNext(); } ?>
                </div>
        </div>
  <?php $rs_main_model->MoveNext(); } ?>
```

It is important to say that if I put some text instead of the second loop, the text appears against every `model_body` but when the loop is done the `variant` values appear only for the first `model_body` and the rest are blank.

My SQL queries are listed below:

```
$catalogue_make =  $_GET['m'];

$sql_all_models =  "SELECT * FROM tbl_catalog WHERE make = '$catalogue_make'"; 
$rs_all_models  =  $db -> Execute($sql_all_models);    

$sql_main_model     = "SELECT * FROM tbl_catalog 
                        WHERE make = '".$rs_all_models->fields['make']."' 
                        GROUP BY model_body";
$rs_main_model  =  $db -> Execute($sql_main_model);    

$sql_variant        = "SELECT * FROM tbl_catalog 
                        WHERE model_body = '".$rs_main_model->fields['model_body']."'";
$rs_variant     =  $db -> Execute($sql_variant);
```

Here is an SQL fiddle of the `GROUP BY` query if this servers for anything:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96044/3

I am not sure this should be achieved with a second loop so any suggestions how to make this work will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
This throws some light on the problem but still cannot get it to work in my code:
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10373392-RESOLVED-Nested-While-Loops-and-mySQL
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I ended up with - if it helps anyone:

```
<?php while (!$rs_main_model->EOF)   { ?>                   
    <div>               
        <div>        
            <h2<?php echo $rs_main_model->fields['model']; ?></h2>
   <?php $sql_variant = "SELECT * FROM tbl_catalog WHERE model_body = '".$rs_main_model->fields['model_body']."'"; $rs_variant = $db -> Execute($sql_variant); ?>
        </div>                                    
        <div>      
                  <?php while (!$rs_variant->EOF) { ?>           
                  <?php echo $rs_variant->fields['variant']; ?>
                  <?php $rs_variant->MoveNext(); } ?>
            </div>
    </div>
<?php $rs_main_model->MoveNext(); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not let sql do all your work? You only need one query. This query gets the table you want then you can use just one loop in php to go through the records :)

```
SELECT model_body, variant FROM tbl_catalog WHERE make = 'M1' GROUP BY model_body, Variant;
```

Comment: If you want to only show the model_body once just use a simple if statement in php to check the previous row and if a match is found don't echo the result.

Comment: Well, I need to get the all the columns + some that are not listed in the example and echo them along with the `variant`. I have simplified the example down to the most basic structure.

Comment: still can be done with sql copy and paste your data structure into fiddle and i can take a look